# Combinations redundant in java programme

Tags: java, combinations

I want to print every possible combinations by using given letters without change letter orders so i wrote this code but it will print every line again and again what is the problem

```
public class Solutions {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        c = "l u k".split(" ");
        Solutions solutions = new Solutions();
        solutions.combi(0);
        System.out.println("Number of combi = " + count);

        System.out.print(max);
    }

    static String[] c;
    static int count = 0;
    static int max = 0;


    public void combi(int start) {

        int j;
        if (start != 0) {
            String str = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
               // System.out.print(c[i]);
                str += c[i];
            }


          //  System.out.println();
            count++;
        }

        for (j = start; j < c.length; j++) {


            combi(start + 1);


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you use Guava, you have tools to facilitate your endeavour

Comment: Try running your code under a debugger, or add printouts so you can see what decisions it's making an why. Watch it run. See where it's doing something unexpected. Fix it. Repeat until it works.

Comment: @keshlam i try it but unexpectedly start variable value change 3 to 2

Comment: When and where does it change? Add printouts until you determine that, and you'll then understand why.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void combi(int start) {
    int j;
    if (start != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
            System.out.print(c[i]);
        }

        System.out.println();
        count++;
    } else {
        for (j = start+1; j <= c.length; j++) {
            combi(j);
        }
    }
}
```